# Raspberry PI Zero W 3V devices

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have an ongoing gps logging project with raspberry pi zero W. There is a 3V device NEO-7 for gps logging powered by raspberries 3V ( pin 17 ) common ground. There are two buttons which need to be debounced. I plan to add 74HC14 (SOP14) and power it by 3V from raspberry, common ground as well.

Should I rather power it by an external 3V regulator or should rasberry handle those two devices just fine. I'm not really sure how much current the 3V can deliver. I have turned off bluetooth and HDMI in order to be sure.

Comment: Unless you specify how much current your devices NEED it is impossible to say, but you are unlikely to exceed the capacity of the 3.3 regulator.

Comment: Thought the limit was 50mA as per https://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Power_pins but that may have been the older boards.  I would look to drop the 5v down for your device as that avoids the Pi on-board regulator (and frying that kills the Pi) and feeds direct from the power supply without touching the Pi circuits.

Comment: The two devices which I'm planning to to use with raspberry pi zero have, according to the datasheet, following current needs: NEO-7M : 17mA @3V ( continuous ) and Nexperia 74HC14 SOP14 ( Static characteristics ):
ICC: ( supply current ) VI = VCC or GND; IO = 0 A;VCC = 6.0 V -> 2uA